# Google Analytics API | Filter Goals with Metric GoalCompletionsAll

Tags: api, filter, analytics

my metric is "GoalCompletionsAll" and I would like to filter that by goals, like only include Goal 1, Goal 2 and Goal 5.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You bet! Instead of using GoalCompletionsAll, use [goalXXCompletions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=goal_conversions&jump=ga_goalxxcompletions).

So your metrics would be: `ga:goal01Completions,ga:goal02Completions,ga:goal05Completions`.

If you're not aware of the query explorer, it's a helpful tool for previewing data - [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).

Comment: Hi blexy, thats a start. But this gives me more than one value (one for each metric). How about a single one value, that sums up all goals?

Comment: `ga:goal01Completions` did not work for me. `ga:goal1Completions` (without `0`) did.

Comment: Is there a field on GA4 that compares with goal completions?